# rJava not loading in Jupyter Notebook with R kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rjava

I'm trying to load library(rJava) in a Jupyter Notebook but I get the following error:

```
stop(gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s", sQuote(package)), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I am usingh the R Kernel in Jupyter notebook.

In RStudio library(rJava) loads just fine but not in Jupyter notebook.

In a terminal when I run: java -version I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
JAVA (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
JAVA HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I don't know why Jupyter Notebook is not recognizing the rJava package.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Turns out it has to do with **environment variables** not being present when the Jupyter Notebook server starts. Try running the following before starting the Jupyter Notebook server (on Linux):

```
sudo R CMD javareconf -e
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/amd64/server"
```

(The `java` in the middle of the path may be different, depending on the version you have installed. If you're using Docker, you'll need to run these commands in a startup bash script before starting the Jupyter Notebook server.)